# SharePoint 2010 change authentication type to Kerberos from NTLM

Tags: 2010, installation, configuration

I have installed SharePoint 2010 Standard edition on a machine along with a VM inside of SQLServer 2008 R2 as (Tier 2) ...By default its on NTLM and classic mode authentication.

When I tried implementing RSSViewer webpart i came to know that I cannot use it with NTLM because of single hop and cannot fetch external contents and need Kerberos to implement and also i am planning to implement SQL Reporting Services and Analysis Services on my portal so Kerberos is essential.

Now need to change my authentication type to Kerberos but no clue how to implement it. Can I go step by step like I did ..I've changed the NTLM type to Kerberos and in IIS verified the authentication methods ..

Can I go slow like first change the type to Kerberos and check if my RSSViewer is working or not..or do I need to create Service Principal Name first for webapplication? I don't want to configure reporting and analysis services at this moment..just kerberos and check RSSViewer...What will be the steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they have posted is good information.

Basically just create the approprate SPNs, then in central admin change over to kerberos.  That's pretty much all I had to do if I remember correctly.

Kerbtray is a good app to make sure you are getting your tickets:  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23018

and I have also used this webpage in the past to make sure it's configured correctly:  http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1434

Unfortunately when I did a kerberos config recently, this website failed to help me out.

Another thing that got me was the rss viewer test will only work if you are using the url set as default in the alternate access mappings.  Any other url (intranet, extranet, custom, internet) used when accessing a page with an rss viewer or in the url put into the rss viewer will still come back saying authenticated feeds are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/affa9c9d-5f04-4522-aaa6-883da01d701f) you need to use [this guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23176).

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos authentication requires additional configuration of infrastructure and environment to function properly. It can only be used for Active Directory domain accounts and thus is not
available in workgroup scenarios or for local accounts

Check this out for the steps in detail: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502602.aspx. Here, You will find RSSViewer webpart scenario as well.